# Python: No of rows are always 9 and does not return affected rows count after UPDATE query

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

This is not something complicated but not sure why is it not working

```
import mysql.connector

def get_connection(host, user, password, db_name):
    connection = None
    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(
            host=host,
            user=user,
            use_unicode=True,
            password=password,
            database=db_name

        )
        connection.set_charset_collation('utf8')
        print('Connected')
    except Exception as ex:
        print(str(ex))
    finally:
        return connection


with connection.cursor() as cursor:
  sql = 'UPDATE {} set underlying_price=9'.format(table_name)
  cursor.execute(sql)
  connection.commit()
  print('No of Rows Updated ...', cursor.rowcount)
```

It always returns 0 no matter what. The same query shows correct count on TablePlus

MysQL API provides [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-cext-affected-rows.html) method but I do not know how to call it as calling against `connection` variable gives error

Comment: it is difficult to check based on the code.  maybe try first verifying that there are indeed rows in the table, and run the sql statement directly e.g. via a graphical interface e.g. DBeaver, to make sure that data in table exists, and indeed has been updated.  Then test with python code. try to use `.affected_rows()` or put `connection.commit()` after `cursor.rowcount`. I am also not sure, but also good to debug from the source to the end.

Comment: @XYZ I already tested `connection.affected_rows()` but it gives error `AttributeError: 'MySQLConnection' object has no attribute 'affected_rows'` I also update code with connection code

Comment: I just tried this `print('No of Rows Updated ...', cursor.rowcount)` changed value and it prints 0

Comment: I updated with one example, it seems that `cursor.rowcount` should works. maybe try `cursor = connection.cursor()`

Comment: @XYZ if you look above I am already using it with cursor.

Comment: I installed import mysql.connector and runs the same code, the first time of running the script, it print the number of rows updated, the second time, it prints 0.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why your code does not work. But i am using pymysql, and it works

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from types import SimpleNamespace
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pymysql

PARAM = SimpleNamespace()
PARAM.DB_user='yourname'
PARAM.DB_password='yourpassword'
PARAM.DB_name ='world'
PARAM.DB_ip = 'localhost'


def get_DB_engine_con(PARAM):
    DB_name =  PARAM.DB_name    
    DB_ip = PARAM.DB_ip 
    DB_user = PARAM.DB_user
    DB_password = PARAM.DB_password

    ## engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://{user}:{pw}@{ip}/{db}".format(user=DB_user,pw=DB_password,db=DB_name,ip=DB_ip))
    conn = pymysql.connect(host=DB_ip, user=DB_user,passwd=DB_password,db=DB_name)    
    cur = conn.cursor()
    return cur, conn   ## , engine

cur, conn = get_DB_engine_con(PARAM)
```

and my data
[image]

if i run the code

```
table_name='ct2'
sql = "UPDATE {} set CountryCode='NL' ".format(table_name)
cur.execute(sql)
conn.commit()
print('No of Rows Updated ...', cur.rowcount)
```

the result `No of Rows Updated ... 10` is printed. and the `NLD` is changed to `NL`

If using mysql.connector

```
import mysql.connector
connection = mysql.connector.connect(
    host=PARAM.DB_ip,
    user=PARAM.DB_user,
    use_unicode=True,
    password=PARAM.DB_password,
    database=PARAM.DB_name
)

cur = connection.cursor()
table_name='ct2'
sql = "UPDATE {} set CountryCode='NL2' ".format(table_name)
cur.execute(sql)
print('No of Rows Updated ...', cur.rowcount)
connection.commit()
```

it still works
and the country code is updated to `NL2` and `No of Rows Updated ... 10` is printed. The second time i run then `No of Rows Updated ... 0` is printed.

Not sure why it does not work on your machine.

Comment: I am not using `pymysql`

Comment: I updated with the example of import mysql.connector, it works on my machine, not sure why it does not work on your machine. Try restart, remove any caches files, and after running the statement then commit().  maybe this helps.